# How to get the column header height of a TListView?

Tags: listview, delphi, delphi-2009

In a `TListView` I want to get the first pixel vertically where the list client area starts. Normally, it starts at 0 but when the header is present it starts at header height.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get header handle (alternative - with corresponding `LVM_GETHEADER` message) and retrieve its size by any method.

```
uses ... commctrl;

var
  h: THandle;
  r: TRect;
begin
  h := ListView_GetHeader(ListView2.Handle);
  GetWindowRect(h, r);
  Caption := IntToStr(r.Bottom - r.Top);
```

Comment: I get an error message at `r.Height.ToString`, but I found the header height by `r.Bottom - r.Top`. Thanks !

Comment: Yes, this helper was not available in d2009 yet.